# Displaying text after selecting an item in a Listpicker

Tags: android, listpicker, app-inventor

I am new to MIT App inventor and I am trying to create a Listpicker with a bunch of names and display them when the Listpicker is clicked. Then when a particular element in the Listpicker is selected it will display more information on that element. I also want to be able to then hide that text once I am done reading it.

This is what I have so far. The list of names comes up but when I click on a name it just goes back to the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the corresponding item from list matchupDetail with the **select list item** block using the selection index of the listpicker

in the AfterPicking event just use the following blocks:

```
set MatchupsDetailDrMario.Text to select list item get global matchupDetail
                                                   matchupsDrMario.SelectionIndex
```

Comment: Do I need to add anything to the BeforePicking event? It still isnt showing up

Comment: you like to select thecorresponding detail information from the detail list... Therefore you should select from *matchupDetail* instead of matchupList... see again my answer...

Comment: Ah okay now I get the text to display. I also decided to change the 2nd listpicker to just a label because I don't want to click it. Thanks